# How to cache new fetch requests in sw-precache

Tags: sw-precache

I am trying to use [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) to enhance the off-line experience in a web app.

As I understand it, the library (and correct me if I am wrong) is to pre-cache all static assets. What about new requests?

Say I want to cache the response of a new get fetch request.

Is there away to override/extend the already provided 
`self.addEventListener('fetch', ...` in the generated sw file

I may be very much missing something here. enlgihten me please...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the option [`runtimeCaching`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#runtimecaching-arrayobject). This option enables caching for those new fetch requests.

You pass it an array of objects specifying what `urlPattern` you want to match, the `handler` you wish to use for the matched request, and some other options you can check in the link.

Comment: I thought I already tested this. This works fine if you are hard refreshing each page you visit.

Here is the real issue I am facing. I have a SPA where I navigate from one page to another. I can see pages get cached but when I refresh pages I visit, I get page not found unless I hard refresh that page then it gets cached properly.

That is why I was asking if we can find away to extend fetch event